# iOS: Wait for existing transition or presentation to finish

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I thought this was simple:
Whenever I get a remote notification while the app is running present a UIAlertController with the message.

The problem is that presenting that alert might happen just as the main app is about to push/present another view controller. In this case, I get ugly error messages like

`pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x7f400c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.`

and the app might get into inconsistent states this way. 
How can I arrange view controller transitions such that they do not get in conflict like this?

Comment: I have just done a promising experiment showing the alert in a separate UIWindow. If this works in the context of the complete app I think I have a nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separating the controllers into two `UIWindow`s solves this problem.
Instead of just presenting the alert on one of the app's view controllers you create a new window like this:

```
let screen = UIScreen.main
let screenBounds = screen.bounds
let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: screenBounds)
alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
let vc = UIViewController()
alertWindow.rootViewController = vc
alertWindow.screen = screen
alertWindow.isHidden = false
vc.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Now the view controllers in the app's main window can push and present other controllers simultaneously to showing alerts.

Comment: I am a bit confused, though, about the fact that the new `UIWindow` disappears when the alert is dismissed. I thought I would have to remove the window manually. Does anybody know why?

Comment: @CaptainFim that might be because new window has been declared as local var and being managed through ARC.